# Julia push! - is not the right command while trying to collect data

Tags: julia

I am struggling with Julia every time that I need to collect data in an array "outside" functions.

If I use `push!(element, array)` I can collect data in the array, but if the code is inside a loop then the array "grows" each time.

What do you recommend?

I know is quite basic :) but thank you!

Comment: Hi and welcome!  It's not clear to me what you want to do exactly.  `push!` appends an element at the end, that's why you see that it grows.

Answer (score 3):

I assume the reason why you do not want to use `push!` is because you have used Matlab before where this sort of operation is painfully slow (to be precise, it is an `O(n^2)` operation, so doubling `n` quadruples the runtime). This is not true for Julia's `push!`, since `push!` uses the algorithm described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis#Dynamic_array) which is only `O(n)` (so doubling `n` only doubles the runtime).

You can easily check this experimentally. In Matlab we have

```
>> n = 100000; tic; a = []; for i = 1:n; a = [a;0]; end; toc
Elapsed time is 2.206152 seconds.

>> n = 200000; tic; a = []; for i = 1:n; a = [a;0]; end; toc
Elapsed time is 8.301130 seconds.
```

so indeed the runtime quadruples for an `n` of twice the size. In contrast, in Julia we have

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

       function myzeros(n)
           a = Vector{Int}()
           for i = 1:n
               push!(a,0)
           end
           return a
       end

       @btime myzeros(100_000);
       @btime myzeros(200_000);
  486.054 μs (17 allocations: 2.00 MiB)
  953.982 μs (18 allocations: 3.00 MiB)
```

so indeed the runtimes only doubles for an `n` of twice the size.

Long story short: if you know the size of the final array, then preallocating the array is always best (even in Julia). However, if you don't know the final array size, then you can use `push!` without losing too much performance.